# Comparison between Harris corner detector vs SURF

Tags: computer-vision, correspondence

I am trying find the differences between two stereo images and I was doing some research. I came across Harris corner algorithm and SURF to solve the correspondence problem. I am unsure what the difference between the two are. Can someone explain to me the benefits of one over the other?

Comment: Harris only says "Hey, here is a corner", while SURF also provides "feature descriptors" that can be used to compare keypoints.

Comment: Here is detailed survey how each works. http://www.eng.auburn.edu/~troppel/courses/7970%202015A%20AdvMobRob%20sp15/literature/%5B2008%5D%20Local%20Invariant%20Feature%20Detectors-%20A%20Survey.pdf

Comment: Which one is faster? Can somebody express this in the manner of complexities?